# Failed to initialise Postgres DB cluster on windows

Tags: postgresql

I am beginning in postgresql, and I have this problem after installing it on windows. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO - *This* forum is specifically for programming related issues, not setup, config and admin. You should take a moment to read the [help] then move you post to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) We are also an English language community so please try and ensure any relevant information is displayed/translated into English.

Answer (score 0):

First Run the PostgreSQL installer using Adminitsrator

Comment: Is the data directory you are trying to use an existing (but empty) directory? If so, please try deleting it and re-installing using administartor